# How can I get 'day of week' for the 'Friday' only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want the day of week for each friday that is coming from my date column in SQL Server.

What I tried so far is,

```
SELECT 
[EntryDate] AS 'Date', 
DATEPART(dw,[EntryDate]) AS 'Week' ,
CASE WHEN
DATEPART(dw,[EntryDate]) = DATEPART(dw,[EntryDate]) AND DATENAME(dw,[EntryDate]) = 'Friday'
THEN
DATENAME(dw,[EntryDate])
END AS 'DayName'
FROM [dbo].[EnergyDetails]
```

Output is:-

[image]

Can anybody please give some focus.

Thanks.

Comment: You've shown the output you don't want; now, can you show the output you *do* want? The word problem isn't doing it for me.

Comment: Hi @VijaykumarHadalgi what I want is, If I have a week no. 4, so I want friday of that perticular week.

Comment: Still not understanding, sorry.

Comment: Hey @AaronBertrand plz check my updated question, hope makes you clear. I am not getting the required output, so dont have a screenshot.

Comment: It's 9 rows - please type it.

Comment: hey, @AaronBertrand, I have added the quiredoutput screenshot. Plz check. Thanks.

Comment: people are ready for a new year,why are you taking the time 4 months back @Adit,if i'm correct then this is what you need `say 2013-11-12-->4-->wednesday--->2013-13-12(i,e fridays date) ?

Comment: Yes. Correct @VijaykumarHadalgi , want such date for each week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls try this:

```
SELECT 
Date,
DATEADD(DD,(7- DATEPART(DW,Date)),c.Date) as 'End Date',
DATENAME(DW,(DATEADD(DD,(6- DATEPART(DW,Date)),Date))) as 'DayName'
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: the o/p is kinda conflicting it give you past/future fridays date,but  i aint no idea if this apply's here

Comment: Yes man. Its working. It is giving the required output. I have to verify it on some data. cheers ! thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, you are a bit wrong. Its showing the fridays but of the last week. What I want is the Friday of the current week. Say todays date, its dmy, 11-12-2013, so day of week is, 4, & in 4th week, friday is on  13-12-2013. Anyways thanks I did it. Plz update ur answer so that I can accept

Comment: pls do add your answer here i'm on cell phone..:)

Comment: @Aditya : heyy can you post what changes you made !! i can jus update

Comment: Yes @VijayKumar. Currently I dont have my system. I will post it on tomorrow itself. Thanks.